# How to determine interval of convergence for power series composition?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a function $f(x) = x\ln(1-x)$ and I'm supposed to use power series representation to determine the interval of convergence.  I'm given the power series $\ln(1-x) = -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k}$.  I'm also given the interval of convergence for this power series, which is $-1 < x < 1$.

Using the rules of combining power series, I wrote the new power series to represent $f(x)$ as  $x\ln(1-x) = -\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k}$ (but I'm not 100% sure if that's correct).

So the last step is to test the end points, because according to some theorem, the name of which I forgot, the interval of convergence will be the same.

This is the part that I'm not sure about.  I thought you test the end points by just plugging them into the series for $x$ and determining if the series will converge or diverge.  Using that method, I found that both $-1$ and $1$ create a series that converges, so I originally said the interval of convergence for the new series is $-1 \le x \le1$.

However, the answer in my book says the actual interval of convergence is $-1 \le x \lt 1$ (so $1$ is not part of the interval of convergence).  Now I'm kind of lost because I don't see how $1$ would cause the series to diverge.  Any help clarifying where I'm making a mistake is appreciated.

Comment: The series $\sum\frac{1}{k}$ diverges. And that's what you get by letting $x=1$ in one of your series.

Comment: how is it that $-1$ converges then?  Is it the alternating series test that you would use for $-1$?

Comment: @Sabien That theorem you are refering to is essentially the Ratiotest. It is inconclusive at end points (the ratio test gives 1) and so they need to be checked independently. Please note that the interval of convergence is obtained by applying the ratiotest in the first place. It gives all values for which the test results in an answer less than 1 (in absolute terms)

Comment: @imranfat Ah yes, thank you.  I remember you can also use the root test depending on the series, correct?  Is the ratio and root test the only tests you use to determine the interval of convergence for a power series?

Comment: The root test can be used usually for series where the base as well as its exponent contain the variable $n$. But when it comes to series to "describe" transcedental functions, the ratio test is used more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}| = \dfrac{k}{k+1}\cdot |x| \to |x|$. So the series converges if $|x| < 1$. At endpoints $1$ and $-1$, the series diverges to $-\infty$, and converges conditionally respectively. So the interval of convergence is: $[-1,1)$